Is it appropriate to use Term-SOFR curve as spot rate curve in bond pricing for simplicity?
everyone, I am coding for a task of some derivatives pricing, and I am a newbie to the quant. Since the term SOFR data is already available in my company's database, I am wondering if it's appropriate to use the Term -SOFR curve as a spot curve to do such as bond pricing job?

Please clarify, what exactly do you mean by bond pricing? For most bonds, you already have an observable price. If you project the bond's cash flows and discount with this curve, you're unlikely to match the observed price. You can match, e.g. US treasury, observed bonds prices with prices calculated by discounting bond cash flows using the yield curve that is build from the observed prices,, which is kind of tautological. What are you trying to do?

Hi @DimitriVulis , I am trying to match a spot rate term structure for cash flows discounting which shall bring me the pv of a bond(ps: I am trying to calculate the plain bond price, and then get the embedded option price by deducting callable bond price from the plain bond price), this does need bootstrapping to generate a zero curve, so the problem is, can I just use Term-SOFR rates in the Qu antlib ZeroRate constructor for plain
bond pricing?

Given your comment, how do you expect a SOFR rate to incorporate credit risk?

@AKdemy Hi, is it OK to use US T-bill yield curve to replace SOFR, or maybe I still need add a credit spread on the risk-free rate?

Unless you price US T-bills, you cannot use an US T-Bill yield curve. Using yield curves will never recover the quoted price perfectly in any case.
